# emacs -nw 8 bit meta

Tags: shell, emacs, metadata

I am trying to set console emacs to use 8-bit meta rather than interpreting it as a character. The reason for this is so I can use meta as a modifier in Vim for my own keybindings. So setting xterm to "Meta Sends Escape" is not an option.

I would think that setting meta-flag would do what I want as described below, but meta-flag no longer appears to be a variable in this version of emacs (23.1.1)

http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs18/emacs%5F6.html

Also the set-input-mode seems to do what I want but it also isn't in my version of emacs.

google: set-input-mode interrupt flow meta quit-char

(Sorry, I can only use 1 link)

Any ideas or alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, 8-bit meta is ancient deprecated stuff.  Nobody wants to waste a whole bit on <kbd>Meta</kbd> anymore.  And with Unicode and all these modern newfangled things, people do not want to be restricted to inputting US-ASCII.  Besides, ¡unɟ sᴉ ǝpoɔᴉu∩

Comment: Interesting, that could explain why it is so hard to find information about it. Do you know any good alternatives?

Comment: @Bostonvaulter: Your reason for wanting 8-bit meta is something in Vim - I don't use it, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps there is some way to get vim to work without 8-bit meta.